# Find and copy all occurrences of a substring from point a to point b to a list

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I'll try to write this in pseudo-code but I am struggling to write the vb.net code myself, as I am rather new to the language.

I would like to find point a in a string and copy all characters until the end of point b.

However the original string contains multiple occurrences of the 'sentence' I want, and as such I would like to attain all of the occurrences in a list.

```
Dim original ="hello mike bye some words hello kate your nice bye" etc.

Dim list As New List(Of String)
Dim pointA As String ="hello"
Dim pointB As String = "bye"

*Psuedo Code*
While not end of string
dim copy As String
--Find first a
--Find first b
--copy all sentence
--list.Add(copy)
--Find next occurrence

essentially the List would now contain:
list(0) = "hello mike bye"
list(1) = "hello kate your nice bye"
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the string methods IndexOf and Substring

```
Dim original ="hello mike bye some words hello kate your nice bye and other strings"
Dim startWord = "hello"
Dim stopWord = "bye"
Dim words = new List(Of String)()

Dim pos1 = original.IndexOf(startWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
Dim pos2 = original.IndexOf(stopWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
while pos1 <> -1 AndAlso pos2 <> -1
    words.Add(original.Substring(pos1, pos2 + stopWord.Length - pos1))
    pos1 = original.IndexOf(startWord, pos1 + 1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    pos2 = original.IndexOf(stopWord, pos2 + 1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
End While

for each s in words
    Console.WriteLine("[" + s + "]")
next
```

Comment: Thank this works perfectly in the test case, however i have just noticed that the original string contains no spaces. so for example .... Dim original ="hellomikebyesomewordshellokateyournicebyeandother strings" is it still possible to find the sub-string in this?

Comment: Did you try? There is no problem with or without spaces